# Regular Expression to remove everything but characters and numbers between Square brackets

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I used

```
value.replaceAll("[^\\w](?=[^\\[]*\\])", "");
```

it works fine if in the following case

```
[a+b+c1 &$&$/]+(1+b&+c&)
```

produces:

```
[abc1]+(1+b&+c&)
```

but in case of following string it only removes the square brackets within square brackets in the first run

```
[a+b+c1 &$&$/[]]+(1+b&+c&)
```

produces:

```
[a+b+c1 &$&$/]+(1+b&+c&)
```

Comment: why is `+` in `a+b+c1` not being removed?.. According to your question it should not be there right?. What if the expression was `a+b+c1 ++++--` .. what should be the output?

Comment: sorry i did a mistake in writing

Comment: Nested brackets cannot be resolved by regex only. Write a parser for this.

Comment: @XeshanJ It would seem that you should do some preprocessing before you make the call to `replaceAll()`.  Please answer your own question.

Comment: @anubhava thanks i get it! i will write a parser for it.

Comment: @anubhava  well writing a complete parser for such a stuff may require a lot of time although i just needed it for small piece of work. is there any work around we can resolve nested brackets with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Translating my comments into an answer*

You can use this simple parsing in Java for your replacement:

```
String s = "[a+b+c1 &$&$/[]]+(1+b&+c&)";
int d=0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch: s.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch == ']')
        d--;
    if (d==0 || Character.isAlphabetic(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch))
        sb.append(ch);
    if (ch == '[')
        d++;
}
System.out.println(sb);
//=> [abc1]+(1+b&+c&)
```

Comment: the only problem with it is that you cannot put unclosed nested bracket

Comment: Yes that's right, brackets should be balanced for this simple approach.